# Can working_directory be user specific

Tags: eclipse

I am on a project where they use launch files. Until now there was one developer, but it is the intention that we are going to work with more developers.

At the moment I see in the launch file:

```
<stringAttribute key="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.WORKING_DIRECTORY" value="/home/john/dev/projects/..."/>
```

But that is a hardwired user. Is there a way to substitute the home directory of the current user for '/home/john'?

Comment: In the _Run/Debug Configurations_ you can set the working directory in the tab _Arguments_: either set to _Default_ (= project directory) or _Other_ using the `workspace_loc` variable.

Comment: Because we have to make several environments we prefer something less labour intensive. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Many values in a launch configuration can contain 'variables' to set the value.

For the working directory you could use `${system_property:user.home}` to get the `user.home` system property:

```
<stringAttribute key="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.WORKING_DIRECTORY" 
  value="${system_property:user.home}/...."/>
```

The Run Configuration for the launch has a 'Variables' button next to the working directory setting on the 'Arguments' tab which will show you the main variables you can use.